# Curl command works fine, while Python requests returns 404

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests, http-status-code-404

Curl

```
curl "https://api.wanikani.com/v2/summary" \ -H "Wanikani-Revision: 20170710" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer <API-KEY>"
```

This command returns the expected json.

Python code

```
import requests

headers = {"Wanikani-Revision": "20170710", "Authorization": "Bearer <API-KEY>"}
res = requests.post('https://api.wanikani.com/v2/summary', headers = headers)

print(res.text)
```

This code returs 404.
{"error":"Not found","code":404}

Comment: curl makes `GET` request by default, where as `requests` does `POST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function only accepts GET. Look https://docs.api.wanikani.com/20170710/#summary

Try:

```
import requests

headers = {"Wanikani-Revision": "20170710", "Authorization": "Bearer <API-KEY>"}
 
res = requests.get('https://api.wanikani.com/v2/summary', headers = headers)

print(res.text)
```